# Meaning of нечто вроде

Tags: словоупотребление

¿Does **нечто вроде паука** mean:

> something like a spider

or

> some kind of spider

or can it mean both?

Comment: May I ask an offtopic question? As far as I understand, you are from US, but you use Spanish-like opening question mark (¿). Is it your personal habit or a sort of new trend in American English? Is there any reason, for instance, for me, to start using it?

Comment: Haha, I use it when I write a question with a colon, since I can't have both a colon and a question mark. I've never seen anyone else do it, but it makes sense to me. I may be OCD, but I just can imagine a question without нечто вроде question mark :)

Answer (score 5):

> Нечто вроде паука.

That phrase means "something like a spider". It implies that you are not sure that it is a spider but it resembles you spider (by color, shape, abilities etc).

> Некий/какой-то вид паука.

It means "some kind of spider".

Comment: Or «паук некого рода», also means «some kind of spider».